# Login via POST does not yield valid session

Tags: node.js, go

I am currently trying to convert a smallish app from nodejs to golang (hence the two tags) but I'm running into a bit of trouble in doing so.

Essentially it is a very simple http POST login which I can't seem to realise. The background is that my university provides a calendar export function and I would like to provide this calendar as a feed that could be added to Google Cal.

Now the thing is that I have the whole thing working in node, but I would really like to be able realise it in go aswell.

The important bit of node code would be

```
var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
var data = {
  u: query.user, // Username
  p: query.password, // Password
};
needle.post(LOGIN_URL, data, {}, function (error, response) {
  //extract cookies etc.
});
```

which is working like a charm but if I try to do the same in go

```
import "github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest"
//...
resp, body, err := gorequest.New().Post(LOGIN_URL).Send("u=user&p=pass").End()
//extract cookies etc.
```

I end up an invalid (timed out) session. I already tried using just net/http in go, which doesn't seem to change anything.

The result the POST request yields is a 302 redirect to an overview page (Btw: it is ASP based). Could it be that this is what's causing the problem, since gorequest then fetches that overview page without the cookies returned in resp, effectively creating a new session that isn't authorized, or am I overlooking something terribly simple?

Comment: I don't see any benefit to using `gorequest` here, other that it may be hiding something from you. Use `net/http`, and see what exactly is happening.

Comment: As JimB said: Use net/htt. And please show whole code and data transferred.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that I found the answer myself by following your advice and using "net/http" and digging a little deeper into what the http.Client actually does. To anyone who might encounter similar problems, here is my solution:

http.Client automatically redirects if it receives a 30x response by the server [see documentation](http://godoc.org/net/http#Client). Although one can override the redirect policy, I was unable to prevent redirection entirely.

Additionally it seems as if the client has a bug (what I would call it at least), as it drops all header upon redirect [see the issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4800) or [in the source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/client.go#L319) where new headers are created.

While searching around in net/http I found http.DefaultTransport which is used by http.Client and does not redirect. It seems somewhat lower level and exactly what I was after. The following piece of code demonstrates how I replaced the line realised with gorequest from above:

```
data := url.Values{"u": {USER}, "p": {PASS}}
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", LOGIN_URL, bytes.NewBufferString(data.Encode()))

//I needed quite some time to figure out that I needed to set the content type accordingly
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
//...
resp, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
//...
//resp.Header["Set-Cookie"] now contains the login/session cookies
```

Although I need to extract cookies myself and set a few header values, the solution works perfectly and I am quite happy with it. If anybody has some improvements to my solution or any other advice I am glad to hear it. And thanks to JimB and Volker :).